# Service is stopping on app close when it didn't before

Tags: java, android, service, handler, bind

I am creating an app that runs a 24 hour timer in the background using a handler in a `Service`. The `Service` should be running at all times, even when the app is fully closed. The `Service` should not end until the `Timer` has fully run out. Originally it was working and the `Service` would continue running in the background even when the app was fully closed but all of a sudden it does not work correctly.

Here is the code for my `Service`:

```
public class SetupTimerPC1 extends Service
{
Handler handler;
Database data;
Intent i, result;
runGraphics runG;
int bucketLevel = 1, bucketExpTotal = 0, totalWater = 0, bucketExp = 0;
float waterAmt = 0;
int timerCount = 0;
Notification notify;
Notification.Builder builder;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}//end onBind function

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent)
{
    super.onRebind(intent);
}//end onRebing

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
{
    return true;
}//end onUnbind

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();

    //setup 24 hour timer
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 600000); //600000 -> wait ten minutes then call runnable
}//end onCreate function

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //get current bucket exp
        data = new Database(SetupTimerPC1.this);
        data.open();
        bucketExp = data.getBucketExp();
        data.close();

        //check experience for current level
        if (bucketExp < 3000)
        {
            bucketLevel = 1;
        }//end if
        else if (bucketExp > 3000 && bucketExp < 6000)
        {
            bucketLevel = 2;
        }//end else if
        else if (bucketExp > 6000 && bucketExp < 9000)
        {
            bucketLevel = 3;
        }//end else if
        else if (bucketExp > 9000 && bucketExp < 12000)
        {
            bucketLevel = 4;
        }//end else if
        else if (bucketExp > 12000)
        {
            bucketLevel = 5;
        }//end else if

        //give resource based on level
        if (bucketLevel == 1)
        {
            waterAmt += .2;
            bucketExp += 1;
        }//end if
        else if (bucketLevel == 2)
        {
            waterAmt += .4;
            bucketExp += 2;
        }//end else if
        else if (bucketLevel == 3)
        {
            waterAmt += .6;
            bucketExp += 3;
        }//end else if
        else if (bucketLevel == 4)
        {
            waterAmt += .8;
            bucketExp += 4;
        }//end else if
        else if (bucketLevel == 5)
        {
            waterAmt += 1.0;
            bucketExp += 5;
        }//end else if
        timerCount++;
        if (timerCount < 144)//144
        {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 600000); //600000
        }//end if
        else
        {
            //pull data
            data = new Database(SetupTimerPC1.this);
            data.open();
            bucketExpTotal = data.getBucketExp();
            totalWater = data.getWaterAmt();
            data.close();

            //add new data to old
            bucketExpTotal += bucketExp;
            totalWater += (int)waterAmt;

            //push data
            data.open();
            data.bucketExpEntry(bucketExpTotal);
            data.waterAmountEntry(totalWater);
            data.bucketLevelEntry(bucketLevel);
            data.close();

            //send notification that resources have been gained
            notifyUser();

            i.putExtra("polarCap1Stat", true);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(i);
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }//end else
    }//end run function
};//end runnable    

public void notifyUser()
{
    //notify user of resource gain 
    result = new Intent(this, runGraphics.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        SetupTimerPC1.this, 
        0, 
        result, 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    notify = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
         .setContentTitle("2023: Water Gained")
         .setContentText("Successfully extracted water.")
         .setTicker("2023")
         .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
         .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alienicon)
         .build();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notify);
}//end notifyUser

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    i = new Intent("polarCap1Status");
    i.putExtra("polarCap1Stat", false);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(i);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
    }//end onStartCommand function


}//end SetupTimerPC1 class
```

This code uses a `Broadcast Receiver` to send a different class a `Boolean` value of whether the `Button` that starts the `Service` can be clicked (meaning when the `Service` starts, it tells the other class that the `Button` cannot be clicked again until the service is complete.)

here is the code i use for starting the `Service`:

```
//start service for timer
startService(new Intent(runGraphics.this, SetupTimerPC1.class));
```

Let me know if anymore code is necessary. I really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Use an alarm manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Service` is still running.  What you are seeing is the device has slept so the timer won't be accurate.  If you check your process list on the device you'll still see your app's process running, even after exiting your `Activity`.  If you need to ensure your `Service` does something at a specific interval (1 min, 1 hour, 1 day, or whatever) then you need to use the `AlarmManager` to ensure the device is awakened so your `Service` can get time to run.  Alternatively, you could use the new `JobScheduler`, but it is Android 5.0+ only.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have this running so it loops 144 times and waits 10 minutes at each iteration of the handler (meaning it will go for 24 hours). So using an AlarmManager will make sure that it is accurately acting at these time intervals? Because the Service seems to be working find until I fully close the app. When I open the app back up it acts like I never clicked the button to start the service and lets me do it again, even though I have a BroadcastReceiver in the service that sends back a boolean to deactivate the button.

Comment: Unless your `Activity` is somehow calling `stopService()` or your `Service` calls `stopSelf()` then the `Service` will generally continue to run.  The exception is if the system comes under memory pressure and starts killing off processes.  This is not very likely for processes with a `Service`, but it is possible.  You can use the `AlarmManager` to schedule a `PendingIntent` to be sent at the desired interval.  Use one for a `BroadcastReceiver` which holds a `Wakelock` and sends an `Intent` to your `Service` via `startService`.  The `Service` will then wake or be created (again) to process.

Comment: Don't forget to have the `Service` release the wakelock when done.  There's actually a compat class which is intended for just this purpose: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: I gave this a shot and it still does the same thing it did before. When the app is closed, the button is able to be clicked again which restarts the service. It is as if the timer is quit when the app is closed.

Comment: Double check your logic on the button. In both cases the service will execute its `onStartCommand` method. If your button is being enabled based on the boolean extra you have set to `false` in the start command `Intent` then it would behave as you describe.

Comment: The logic on the button seems fine. Upon execution of onStartCommand the button is set to off and then when the timer has completed, the button is set to on.

Comment: I see now that the handler I was using was working correctly after testing it with a shorter amount of time and closing the app. I just need to basically make sure that it does not activate the button until the service has complete. The broadcast receiver that enables the button at the end of the service is not working correctly since the button activates upon the closing of the app even though the service has not completed yet.

Comment: I don't quite follow, but it sounds like you're on the right track.  Just remember: `onStartCommand()` is called any time an `Intent` is sent to a `Service` via the `startService()` method.  If your `Activity` is waiting for the timer base broadcast when it first starts up to see if it should enable its button, it has a flaw because the timer runs every 10 minutes.